# How do I loop through a function that splits string of ints in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here is what I have and I want to loop through this set

```
select value from fxsplitint('1223,123,123',',')
```

fxsplitint is a function created to split the string on a delimiter

I want to say print each value after I do something with it

Comment: Have you had a look at this - [Split String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a temp table to iterate through all the values in your list returned by the function.

```
DECLARE @rowcount int;
DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @value int;

SET i = 0;

SELECT id = identity(int, 1,1), a.* INTO #yourtemptable FROM (
   SELECT value FROM fxsplitint('1223,123,123',',')
)

WHILE (@i <= @rowcount)
   BEGIN
     SET @value = value FROM #yourtemptable WHERE id = @i;

     SELECT @value; --output your value

     SET @i = @i + 1
   END
DROP TABLE #yourtemptable;
```